# Can I create a Airflow DAG dynamically using REST API?

Tags: python, airflow, airflow-api

**Is it possible to create a Airflow DAG programmatically, by using just REST API?**

## Background

We have a collection of models, each model consists of:

- A collection of SQL files that need to be run for the model
- We also keep a JSON file for each model which defines the dependencies between each SQL file.

The scripts are run through a Python *job.py* file that takes a script file name as parameter.

Our models are updated by many individuals so we need to update our DAG daily. What we have done is created a scheduled Python script that reads all the JSON files and for each model creates in memory DAG that executes each model and its SQL scripts as per the defined dependencies in the JSON config files. What we want to do is to be able to recreate that DAG visually within Airflow DAG programmatically and then execute it, rerun failures etc.

I did some research and per my understanding Airflow DAGs can only be created by using decorators on top of Python files. Is there another approach I missed using REST API?

Here is an example of a JSON we have:

```
{
    "scripts" :[
        "Script 1": {
            "script_task" : "job.py",
            "script_params" : {
                "param": "script 1.sql"
            },
            
            "dependencies": [
                "Script 2",
                "Script 3"
            ]
        },
        "Script 2": {
            "script_task" : "job.py",
            "script_params" : {
                "param": "script 2.sql"
            },
            
            "dependencies": [
                "Script 3"
            ]
        },
        "Script 3": {
            "script_task" : "job.py",
            "script_params" : {
                "param": "script 3.sql"
            },
            
            "dependencies": [
                
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: could you show example `json`?

Comment: not sure if there is a solution 'from box'. you can create a plugin which will generate dags from json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Airflow dags are python objects, so you can create a dags factory and use any external data source (json/yaml file, a database, NFS volume, ...) as source for your dags.

Here are the steps to achieve your goal:

1. create a python script in your dags folder (assume its name is dags_factory.py)
2. create a python class or method which return a DAG object (assume it is a method and it is defined as `create_dag(config_dict)`)
3. in the main, load your file/(any external data source) and loop over dags configs, and for each dag:

```py
# this step is very important to persist the created dag and add it to the dag bag
globals()[<dag id>] = create_dag(dag_config)
```

So without passing in the details of your java file, if you have already a script which creates the dags in memory, try to apply those steps, and you will find the created dags in the metadata and the UI.

Here are some tips:

- Airflow runs the dag file processor each X seconds ([conf](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/configurations-ref.html#min-file-process-interval)), so no need to use an API, instead, you can upload your files to S3/GCS or a git repository , and load them in the main script before calling the `create_dag` method.
- Try to imporve your json schema, for ex, `scripts` can be an array
- For the method `create_dag`, I will try to simplify the code (according to what I understood from your json file):

```py
from datetime import datetime
from json import loads
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash import BashOperator


def create_dag(dag_id, dag_conf) -> DAG:
    scripts = dag_conf["scripts"]
    tasks_dict = {}
    dag = DAG(dag_id=dag_id, start_date=datetime(2022, 1, 1), schedule_interval=None)  # configure your dag
    for script_name, script_conf in scripts.items():
        task = BashOperator(
            bash_command=f"python {script_conf['script_task']} {(f'{k}={v}' for k, v in script_conf['script_params'])}",
            dag=dag
        )
        tasks_dict[script_name] = {
            "task": task,
            "dependencies": script_conf["dependencies"]
        }
    for task_conf in tasks_dict.values():
        for dependency in task_conf["dependencies"]:
            task_conf["task"] << tasks_dict[dependency]["task"]  # if you mean the inverse, you can replace << by >>
    return dag
    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # create a loop if you have multiple file
    # you can load the files from git or S3, I use local storage for testing
    dag_conf_file = open("dag.json", "r")
    dag_conf_dict = loads(dag_conf_file.read())
    dag_id = "test_dag"  # read it from the file
    globals()[dag_id] = create_dag(dag_id, dag_conf_dict)
```

P.S: if you will create a big number of dags in the same script (one script to process multiple json file), you may have some performance issues because Airflow scheduler and workers will re-run the script for each task operation, so you will need to improve it using [magic loop](https://medium.com/apache-airflow/airflows-magic-loop-ec424b05b629) or the [new syntax](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/dynamic-dag-generation.html#optimizing-dag-parsing-delays-during-execution) added in 2.4

Comment: Can you elaborate on the create_dag method? Is there a REST API that creates the DAG? What creates the DAG?

Comment: I just updated my answer by adding the tips part, can you check it?

Comment: Thanks @Hussein my question was more specific to an available Airflow REST API. It seems what you are describing above is about uploading a Python file as a Airflow processor which I assume cannot be done remotely.

Comment: There is no API to create dags, and no need to upload the python script, you create the script one time in the dags folder, and you configure it to process the remote json files. For the json files location, you can use GDrive, Git, S3, GCS, Dropbox, ... or any storage you want, then you will be able to upload/update json files and the dags will be updated

Comment: Ok thanks - I guess then there is no API which is what I was looking for e.g. to be able to create the DAG from a remote server. Marking as solved. Appreciate if you can add the comment about lack of API on your answer at the top for other users coming to this question.